# display the information of the person once selected autocomplete jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete plugin to provide suggestions of names from the database. What I am trying to do is to display the information of the person once selected. Can someone give me an idea on how and where will I pass and get the id (primary key) of the selected person?

**js**

```
  $('input[name="name"]').autoComplete({
      minChars: 1,
      source: function(term, response){
           $.getJSON('names.php', { name: term }, function(data){ 
            var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el });
            response(arr);
        }); 
      },
      onSelect: function(){
          //get id -> show info
      } 
  });
```

**names.php**

```
     require 'con.php';

     $term = $_GET['name'];
     $arr = array();

     $query = mysqli_query($connection, 
            "SELECT 
                  id,
                  firstname, 
                  middlename, 
                  lastname 
             FROM mytbl 
             WHERE firstname LIKE '%$term%' || 
                   middlename LIKE '%term%' || 
                   lastname LIKE '%term%'");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
           $arr[] = $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['middlename'] . " " . $row['lastname'];
       }

   echo json_encode($arr);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I imagine if you are returning a name, you could return it with a `data` value in it. `'<span data-userid="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['firstname'] . " " . $row['middlename'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " " . $row['extension_name'].'</span>'` then snatch it using `.data('userid')`

Comment: Also, your `mysqli_` is easily injectable. You should use prepared value/param

Comment: @Rasclatt   I don't know if I'm doing it right. The <span> tag was being displayed on the suggestions. And on select it returns `<span data-userid=` .

Comment: I've never used the autocomplete, let me try what you have and see.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is return multidimensional array from PHP script and handle it in jQuery script.

So your **PHP** snippet should look like this.

```
<?php
$arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $name = $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['middlename'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " " . $row['extension_name'];
    $ar = array();
    $ar['label'] = $name;
    $ar['value'] = $name;
    $ar['id'] = $row['id'];
    $arr[] = $ar;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Now **jQuery** code look something like this,

```
$('input[name="official_name"]').autoComplete({
    minChars: 1,
    source: function(term, response) {
        $.getJSON('names.php', {
            official_name: term
        }, function(data) {
            var arr = $.map(data, function(el) {
                return el
            });
            response(arr);
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var id=ui.item.id;
        console.log("Selected item ID => "+ id);
    }
});
```

Above code returns multidimensional array with Name and ID. jQuery autocomplete expect label and/or value as key from returned array to display it in drop-down.

> The label property is displayed in the suggestion listand the value will
>   be added into the textbox after the user selected something
>   from the list.

When you select any item you just have to use `ui.item.id` for accessing the id of the selected the item.